# variable value is lost outside the function

Tags: jquery

Variable focusedOpt value is lost on down arrow key ,Iam able to focus first element on down arrow key ,Iam having trouble focusing next element on keydown arrow
The code:

```
var focusedOpt;
$(function () {
  $(document).on("keydown", function () { CM_onKeyup(event) });
});
function CM_onKeyup(e) {
   if (e.keyCode == enums.keyboard.DOWN_ARROW) {
      if (!focusedOpt) {
         focusedOpt = optList.first().trigger("focus");
      } else if (focusedOpt.length > 0) {
         focusedOpt = focusele.nextAll("div[CMisShown='1']").first().trigger("focus");
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not passing your event to your function properly with the structure that you currently have in place.  You have 1 of 2 ways of passing the event properly into the function:

Option 1:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on("keydown", function (event) { CM_onKeyup(event) });
});
```

Option 2:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on("keydown", CM_onKeyup);
});
```

I would recommend trying Option 2 first and see what happens.

Comment: I tried with the above solution still the same , second time key down arrow is not recognized